# i want to add input value to the var whos equal to the first input value

Tags: javascript

```js
function onbtntime(sec) {
  var hours;
  var minutes;
  var day;
  var sec;

  if (isNaN(sec)) {
    alert("please enter a number");
    sec = 0;
  }
  if (Number(sec) <= 0) {
    alert("Please enter a positive number");
    sec = 0;
  } else if (sec == undefined) {
    sec = 0;
  } else if (sec >= 60) {

    minutes = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    sec = Math.round(sec % 60);
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
      minutes = Math.round(minutes % 60);
      if (hours >= 24) {
        day = Math.floor(hours / 24);
        hours = Math.round(hours % 24);

      }
    }
  }
  if (hours == undefined) {
    hours = 0;
  }
  if (minutes == undefined) {
    minutes = 0;
  }
  if (day == undefined) {
    day = 0;
  }
  id_p.innerHTML = "Time- " + "Day/s: " + day + " ,hours: " + hours + " ,minutes: " + minutes + " ,sec: " +
    sec;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Welcome to my Time calculator </h2>
    <p id="id_p">Change Second to day/s, hours and minutes.</p>
    <label>Enter your sec</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_input" />
    <button type="button" id="id_button" onclick="onbtntime(parseInt(id_input.value))">שלח</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my code i want that when the user add one or thousand inputs value after the first one they calculate and out the correct time. mmm for example i just want that after i send the input value 500 the output be:
 (Time- Day/s: 0 ,Hours: 0 ,minutes: 8 ,sec: 20)
and if send the input value 500 the output be:
 (Time- Day/s: 0 ,Hours: 0 ,minutes: 16 ,sec: 40)
and so on...
sorry for my bad English 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to store your seconds in global variable in this case.

```js
let secs = 0;

function onbtntime(sec) { 

  if (!Number(sec) || sec <= 0) {
    alert("Please enter a number greater than zero!");
    return;
  }
  
  let
    hours = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    day = 0;

  secs += sec;

  minutes = Math.trunc(secs / 60);
  sec = secs % 60;

  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = Math.trunc(minutes / 60);
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    if (hours >= 24) {
      day = Math.trunc(hours / 24);
      hours = hours % 24;
    }
  }

  console.log("Time- " + "Day/s: " + day + ", Hours: " + hours + ", minutes: " + minutes + ", sec: " + sec);
}

//onbtntime("u");
//onbtntime(0);
onbtntime(3600);
onbtntime(86400);
onbtntime(63);
onbtntime(90116);
onbtntime(3);
```

Comment: thank u your code its what i want only one problam if the user press sec smaller then 60 its not calculate how can i fix it?

Comment: I changed the code. It’s suspicious you’re not able to make such a small change. Is it your school work?

Comment: Thank you for the help. hhhh not it just because iam stupid and lazy. nop.

Comment: Ok. You should mark this as answer if you’re satisfied. Also you can upvote if you find it well coded.

Answer (score 0):

Just add global variable for your global numbers (I made object called result) and assign it's value and new input value every time user presses button.

```js
var result = {
  hours: 0,
  min: 0,
  days: 0,
  sec: 0
};

function onbtntime(sec) {
  var hours;
  var minutes;
  var day;
  var sec;

  if (isNaN(sec)) {
    alert("please enter a number");
    sec = 0;
  }
  if (Number(sec) <= 0) {
    alert("Please enter a positive number");
    sec = 0;
  } else if (sec == undefined) {
    sec = 0;
  } else if (sec >= 60) {

    minutes = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    sec = Math.round(sec % 60);
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
      minutes = Math.round(minutes % 60);
      if (hours >= 24) {
        day = Math.floor(hours / 24);
        hours = Math.round(hours % 24);

      }
    }
  }
  if (hours == undefined) {
    hours = 0;
  }
  if (minutes == undefined) {
    minutes = 0;
  }
  if (day == undefined) {
    day = 0;
  }
  result.hours += hours;
  result.min += minutes;
  result.days += day;
  result.sec += sec;
  id_p.innerHTML = "Time- " + "Day/s: " + result.days + " ,hours: " + result.hours + " ,minutes: " + result.min + " ,sec: " +
    result.sec;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Welcome to my Time calculator </h2>
    <p id="id_p">Change Second to day/s, hours and minutes.</p>
    <label>Enter your sec</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_input" />
    <button type="button" id="id_button" onclick="onbtntime(parseInt(id_input.value))">שלח</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not calculate it like i want, in this code for example if i press 6000 and then again 6000 the output is (Time- Day/s: 0 ,hours: 2 ,minutes: 80 ,sec: 0) and not (Time- Day/s: 0 ,hours: 3 ,minutes: 20 ,sec: 0) like i want it

Comment: Have you figured out what you want or no?

Comment: Ucho did what i wanted. thank u anyway for trying to help